# Change the rotation of a standalone colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a standalone colorbar that I would like to make vertical :

```
cb_colors = ["#41fdfe", "blue", "brown", "grey"]
num_colors = len(cb_colors)
cmap_ = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cb_colors)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.9, 0.1])

cb = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, orientation='horizontal',
                           cmap=cmap_, norm=plt.Normalize( - 0.5 , num_colors - 0.5 ))

cb.set_ticks(range(num_colors))
cb.ax.set_xticklabels(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

I've tried `oriental = 'vertical'`  in  `matplotlib.colorbar` but it doesnt seem to work. I find this as a result [image] but I would like this :

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: should be `orientation='vertical'` right? Can you describe how it doesn't work and maybe what you do want to achieve? replacing `horizontal` with `vertical` in your code does seem to work when you also do `cb.ax.set_yticklabels` instead of `cb.ax.set_xticklabels`

Comment: Other than specifying the vertical of the color bar, I think we can modify the code to the following. `ax = fig.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 1.0]);cb.ax.set_yticklabels(["A", "B", "C", "D"], rotation=90)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things you need to do:

1. change the dimension, the order in [`add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) is `[left, bottom, width, height]` so we need to switch the last two
2. provide the correct orientation `orientation='vertical'`
3. set y instead of x ticks: `cb.ax.set_yticklabels(["A", "B", "C", "D"])`

Code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cb_colors = ["#41fdfe", "blue", "brown", "grey"]
num_colors = len(cb_colors)
cmap_ = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(cb_colors)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.80, 0.1, 0.9])

cb = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, orientation='vertical',
                           cmap=cmap_, norm=plt.Normalize( - 0.5 , num_colors - 0.5 ))

cb.set_ticks(range(num_colors))
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

Result:

[image]